# TKinter dealing with multiple monitors and image display

Tags: python, tkinter

I have functioning code but there are a few things which I would like to change about it but don't know how to so thought i'd ask here. My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


#Define the target, source and output arrays. Source has to be completely white otherwise it kills everything
def initialize(x,y):
    xarr = np.zeros(x)
    yarr = np.zeros(y)
    target = np.meshgrid(xarr,yarr)
    target = target[0]
    source = np.meshgrid(xarr,yarr)
    source = source[0]
    output = np.meshgrid(xarr,yarr)
    output = output[0]
    for i in range(x):
        for n in range(y):
            source[n][i] = 1
    return target, source, output

# creates trap between XTrapMin-XTrapMax and YTrapMin-YTrapMax on Array
def trap(xtmi,xtma,xs,ytmi,ytma,ys,array):
    for i in range(xs):
        if xtmi < i < xtma:
            for n in range(ys):
                if ytmi < n < ytma:
                    array[n][i] = 255
    return

#Returns the amplitude of a complex number
def Amplitude(x):
    if isinstance(x, complex):
        return np.sqrt(x.real**2+x.imag**2)
    else:
        return np.abs(x)

#Returns the phase of a complex number
def Phase(z):
        return np.angle(z)

#Main GS algorithm implementation using numpy FFT package
#performs the GS algorithm to obtain a phase distribution for the plane, Source
#such that its Fourier transform would have the amplitude distribution of the plane, Target.
def GS(target,source):
    A = np.fft.ifft2(target)
    for i in range(5):
        B = Amplitude(source) * np.exp(1j * Phase(A))
        C = np.fft.fft2(B)
        D = Amplitude(target) * np.exp(1j * Phase(C))
        A = np.fft.ifft2(D)
    output = Phase(A)
    return output

#Make array into PIL Image
def mkPIL(array):
    im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(array))
    return im

def up():
    global ytmi
    global ytma
    ytmi -= 10
    ytma -= 10
    return 

def down():
    global ytmi
    global ytma
    ytmi += 10
    ytma += 10
    return

def right():
    global xtmi
    global xtma
    xtmi += 10
    xtma += 10
    return

def left():
    global xtmi
    global xtma
    xtmi -= 10
    xtma -= 10
    return

xtmi = 125
xtma = 130
xs = 1024
ytmi = 0
ytma = 5
ys = 768


root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
def main():
    app = Lower(root)
    root.mainloop()

class Lower:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master).pack()
        self.displayimg = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Display', width = 25, command = self.plot)
        self.displayimg.pack()
        self.makewidg()
    def makewidg(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(100,100), frameon=False)  #changing figsize doesnt cange the size of the plot display
        self.fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0)
        self.fig.tight_layout()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.set_yticklabels([])                        
        self.ax.set_xticklabels([])
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.master)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(expand=True)
        self.canvas.figure.tight_layout()
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.new_window()
    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel()
        self.app = Display(self.newWindow)
    def plot(self): 
        global xtmi, xtma, xs, ytmi, ytma, ys, i
        target,source,output=initialize(xs,ys)
        trap(xtmi,xtma,xs,ytmi,ytma,ys,target)
        output = GS(target,source)
        self.ax.imshow(output, cmap='gray')
        self.ax.set_yticklabels([])                        
        self.ax.set_xticklabels([])
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.ax.clear()

    def kill(self): 
        root.destroy()

class Display:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.up = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Up', width = 25, command = up)
        self.up.pack()
        self.down = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Down', width = 25, command = down)
        self.down.pack()
        self.right = tk.Button(self.frame, text =  'Right', width = 25, command = right)
        self.right.pack()
        self.left = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Left', width = 25, command = left)
        self.left.pack()
        self.kill = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Kill', width = 25, command = self.kill)
        self.kill.pack()
    def kill(self): 
        root.destroy()
main()
```

Currently the button displayimg from the class Lower is displayed above the image, is there a way in which I can have the display button on the Display class and still have it manipulate the image on the Lower screen? Also, I intend to display the window opened by Lower on a separate monitor, but can't drag it seeing as it is fullscreen, is there a way around that I can get it on my second monitor?

---

I try that as such:

```
self.displayimg = tk.Button(self.top, text = 'Display', width = 25, command = Lower.plot(Lower)) 
self.displayimg.pack()
```

But this causes a misreference I think as I get an error code

> `AttributeError: type object 'Lower' has no attribute 'ax'`

Comment: It's not the job of `tkinter` to deal with multiple screens. Your Window Manager have to deal with it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have an idea of how I can transfer the display button to the second window?

Comment: ***" button displayed above the image"***: Open another `Toplevel` window, place the `Button` there and move this window to the other screeen.

Comment: My main problem is that I try that as such

self.displayimg = tk.Button(self.top, text = 'Display', width = 25, command = Lower.plot(Lower))
        self.displayimg.pack()

But this causes a misreference I think as I get an error code

AttributeError: type object 'Lower' has no attribute 'ax'

Comment: ***"AttributeError: type object 'Lower'"***: There a **two** errors in  `command = Lower.plot(Lower)`. **1.** Read [Why is Button parameter “command” executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared) **2.** You are using `Lower.` which is a `class defenition` instead of `<ref to instance Lower>.` which ist a `class object`.

Comment: But from my limited understanding of OOP I'm not initiating an instance of `Lower` though? How would i reference the instance of `Lower`

Currently I have `command = lambda: Lower.plot()` but I am obviously missing the parameter. I don't understand enough of how the classes are initialized to see where the reference to the `Lower` window is stored.

Comment: ***"I'm not initiating an instance of Lower though? "***: Here: `app = Lower(root)`, `class Lower` get instantiated and `app` holds the reference to the `Lower` instance.

Comment: Thank you so much I'm sorry for asking so many questions.

Comment: Is your issue solved? Does the `Button` show up on the second Screen?

Answer (score 0):

**Call to Lower.plot**

You are using `Lower.plot` as your button command. It needs one argument, `self` which must be an instance of Lower - so `Lower.plot(Lower)` is passing a class where an instance is expected. Instead you need to use the app instance you've made, and call app.plot(). The arguement `self` is automatically the instance itself, this is fundamental to OOP in python. Calling the method on an instance passes `self` as the first arg, so it's missing from the call. Calling `Lower.plot(...)` is calling the method on the class `Lower`, so there is no instance, and you have to supply your own. I'd avoid calling methods without an instance like this in this situation, and use your `app` instance.

**Command for the display button**

Your button creation becomes something like:
`self.displayimg = tk.Button(self.top, text = 'Display', width = 25, command = app.plot)`
If you need to pass additional args to plot, you need to delay the function call so it happens on click, not on creation of the button. You can use `lambda : app.plot("red", 10, whatever)` to make a nameless function, taking no arguments, that when called will go on to call app.plot with the given args.

**Positioning the window**

You can control the position of the app window using `wm_geometry`:

```
app.wm_geometry("200x200+100+500")
```

Will cause the app window to be 200px by 200px, positioned 100px left and 500px down from the origin, and on a windows machine, this is the top left corner of your primary monitor. You can keep the width and height the same and just move the window with eg

```
app.wm_geometry("+100+500")
```

You can use more scripting to build the string `+{xpos}+{ypos}` with whichever values you like to match your desktop layout.